# How to solve the discord chatbot didnt reply message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my python code for the discord chatbot that I want to create:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

chatbot = GenericAssistant('intents.json')
chatbot.train_model()
chatbot.save_model()

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!"):
        response = chatbot.request(message.content[2:])
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And when I run the code it will occur these errors:

```
ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "chatbot.py", line 27, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(responses)
  File "anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1538, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

How can I do to solve these error?

The output should be like:
i: !hi
bot: hello

Answer (score 1):

`response` is an empty string. It then tries to send an empty string, yeilding the error.

Edit: It seems you might want to look up [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) instead of using an alpha third party library which provides nothing of value as of now.

Comment: actually i follow the tutorial from web but they can run without this error

Comment: Don't follow stuff blindly.

Comment: i have do many research but all of them are using same method. Do you have any different method to solve this error?

Comment: I don't know what neuralintents is. I also don't know why you are not using the command system provided by the library.

Comment: the neuralintents is used to train the bot from the json file and make it possible to respond to message that user send

Comment: Don't use it, it is not providing anything new. Read discord.py library docs.

Comment: I have a bit confuse about it. May I have an example to refer?

Comment: Have a look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html. I have also edited the answer to include it. You might want to accept it at this point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).